# How do you pronounce “103rd”?

Tags: numbers

The number 103 can be pronounced as “One hundred and three” or “One o three”. 
Can “103rd” be pronounced as “One hundred and third” or “One o third?” (Especially in referring to a name of a street, like 103rd St)

edit: typo. One hundred or third → One hundred and third

Comment: The 103rd Regiment would be "the One Hundred Third Regiment".

Comment: I say *one hundred and third*.

Comment: I would say “a hundred and third street” “The Hundred and Third Regiment”

Comment: For the one hundred third time, it is one hundred third.

Comment: @ab2 Yes, I agree that’s what I was taught too, but nobody I know says that including me, unless I’m taking a test on it. :-)

Comment: @ab2, "one hundred third" is how Americans say "103rd", "one hundred **and** third" is how everyone else says it.

Comment: Hear it pronounced in this video on the logo for the 103rd Indianapolis 500... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PepnzqmgS9k

Comment: @MichaelHarvey They repeat that rule constantly in US schools ("Don't use 'and'!") because people hardly ever follow it (unless it is for dollars and cents and then USians tend to explicitly drop the 'and')

Comment: In British English, it's the other way around: teacher: say this (points to "103rd" on blackboard). Child: one hundred third. Teacher: No! One hundred and third!

Answer (score 4):

It would be 'A hundred third' or 'A hundred and third'. replacing the pronunciation of zero with 'o' is a colloquial shortcut. And then what would you say in the case of 100th or 1000th?

you only replace zeros with 'o' when saying the number and keep it with regular zeros when saying the ordinal number(1st, 2nd, third...)

[Source of shortcut claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_for_the_number_0_in_English)

Comment: Please don't simply link: links change (even Wikipedia). Summarise the relevant arguments and provide a citation (and a link; the citation is more rot-resistant). Stack Exchange is intended to stand on its own, like Wikipedia; to do this it needs to contain all relevant information itself, referencing outside repositories as needed.

Comment: I would probably say "one hundred third", not "a hundred third".

Comment: @GEdgar Yeah you a probably right. I am from the deep south so many times I hear 'a hundred' and 'one hundred' get interchanged.

Answer (score 2):

As you've noted, 103, can be pronounced as "one hundred three" or "one hundred and three". Additionally it can be pronounced beginning with an "a" instead of "one". My research into this question has been both confusing and enlightening. I thought that one of the things that distinguished BrE from AmE was that in BrE "and" is spoken before saying numbers 1 through 99 after saying "hundred", "thousand", "million", "billion" etc. Here's a chart from [mathisfun.com](https://www.mathsisfun.com/numbers/counting-names-1000.html) to illustrate (I have highlighted the extra "and"s in BrE).:

> 101       
>  US: one hundred one
>  UK: one hundred ***and*** one
>  999
>   
>  US: nine hundred ninety-nine
>  UK: nine hundred ***and***
>   ninety-nine
>
> 1,101
>  US: one thousand, one hundred one
>  UK: one thousand, one
>   hundred **and** one
>  15,016 
>  US: fifteen thousand, sixteen
>   UK: fifteen thousand, ***and*** sixteen
>  112,621
>  US: one
>   hundred twelve thousand, six hundred twenty-one
>   *UK: one hundred **and** twelve thousand, six hundred **and** twenty-one*
>
> **Millions and More**
>
> 191,232,891
>  US: one hundred ninety-one million, two hundred
>   thirty-two thousand, eight hundred ninety-one
>  UK: one hundred
>   ***and*** ninety-one million, two hundred ***and*** thirty-two thousand, eight hundred ***and*** ninety-one

This phenomenon is also attested in the Wikipedia article on English numerals:

> 999,000
>  nine hundred and ninety-nine thousand (inclusively British
>   English, Irish English, Australian English, and New Zealand
>   English)
>
> nine hundred ninety-nine thousand (American English)
>   [English numerals (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals)

And if you want another source, check out the text to speech examples for both American and British speakers at this [site](https://www.texttospeechfree.com/). I recommend you type the number "111" because the difference is hard to discern with certain numbers, and "111" is clear. You can see that for the speakers of English from Canada, Australia, Britain and India the "and" is clearly audible, whereas in the American version it isn't.

However, this practice of not using "and" when reading out numbers by Americans is not universal:

> In American English, many students are taught not to use the word and
>   anywhere in the whole part of a number, so it is not used before the
>   tens and ones. It is instead used as a verbal delimiter when dealing
>   with compound numbers. Thus, instead of "three hundred and
>   seventy-three," "three hundred seventy-three" would be said. Despite
>   this rule, some Americans use the and in reading numbers containing
>   tens and ones as an alternative variant.
>   [English Numerals (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_numerals)

[Illinois Democratic candidate: "I am running for the hundred and seventh district..."](https://youtu.be/uR_8rEz2kME?t=9)
[WTHR (Indianapolis-based) anchor says "one hundred and seven"](https://youtu.be/7oLOyLuczV8?t=5)

All this information has made me uncertain, but it's clear many Americans say the "and" in numbers like this. I don't speak for all people, I can only tell you what I hear.

As you are specifically asking about an ordinal number and not a cardinal number, I'll give some information I've found about this topic specifically. See this question and answer on a Word Reference forum thread:

> Question: Is this a way to say ordinal numbers for large numbers?
>   1,234,295,345
>  one billion two hundred thirty-four million two
>   hundred ninety-five thousand three hundred forty-fifth?

There are only two answers, both American users, and both seem to agree that the OP is correct. Note, no "and" before the "forty-fifth"
[Word Reference forum link](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/saying-ordinal-numbers-after-thousand-1-234-295-345.3173473/)

You can also go to the text to speech site I linked and type in 103rd or 111th and see that the "and" is not pronounced.

On the other hand, there are plenty of examples of the opposite.

In many other text to speech programs the American speaker says "hundred and third"

[American saying the "Hundred and First Airborne"](https://youtu.be/FrWZv-dXbR0?t=538)
[American saying "There is no organisation in the world that can do what the Hundred and First does"](https://youtu.be/3tOBf2BfC48?t=43)
[American saying "Hundred and Seventy Third Airborne](https://youtu.be/KCoaVvPm_H4?t=827)
[American saying "hundred and tenth anniversary", talking about a Harley Davidson](https://youtu.be/WonR4awqdl4?t=8)
[American saying "hundred and tenth anniversary"](https://youtu.be/lFsssyEoiKw?t=39)

So this question is way outside my knowledge of how people around the world do or should pronounce 103rd. From my experience in BrE you can say it:

A hundred and third
or
One hundred and third

and in AmE I have heard examples of both the above with and without the "and".

There may also be more informal vernacular ways of saying it such as "one oh third".

Answer (score 2):

In New Yawk, where these types of numbers are used multiple times daily, there are customary differentiations:

For 1,2,3, - or, first, second and third:

"I live at 301 (302,309...310) 102nd St.  - on the 103rd. floor"

**"I live at** ***three oh one (three oh two, three oh nine...three ten) a hundred and second street*** - **on the** ***hundred and third floor."***

"I live at 125, 125th St. - on the 125th floor."

**"I live at** ***one twenty-five, a hundred and twenty-fifth street*** - **on the** ***hundred (and) twenty-fifth floor."*** (the "and" in parentheses is optional)

As I stated, these are customs - not rules. They self-perpetuate because nobody wants to look like a non-native.